# How to show more than one event per day in my php calendar code

Tags: php, mysqli

My calendar works beautifully as written however if I add another event for the same day it will only show the first event recorded in the database. I need to be able to show more than one event for the same day.

I tried using a for/next loop and a while loop in the code that pulls the info from the db. Either one will not work with the way the code is written. This link will show you the working calendar as written: [Grims World Blog](https://blog.trans-galactic.com)
This is my code:

```
<?php
$cMonth = isset($_REQUEST["month"]) ? $cMonth = intval($_REQUEST["month"]) : $cMonth = date("m");
$cYear = isset($_REQUEST["year"]) ? $cYear = intval($_REQUEST["year"]) : $cYear = date("Y");
$prev_year = $cYear;
$prev_year2 = $cYear-1;
$next_year = $cYear;
$next_year2 = $cYear+1;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;
 if ($cMonth == 12 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $next_year2;
 } elseif ($cMonth == 1 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $prev_year2;
}
$short_days = array('1'=>'Sun', '2'=>'Mon', '3'=>'Tue', '4'=>'Wed', '5'=>'Thu', '6'=>'Fri', '7'=>'Sat');
$day=date('d');
$endDate=date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,$day,$cYear));
echo "<table width='100%' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='5'><tr bgcolor='white'>\n";
echo "<td align='left'><a class='caldate3' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=$prev_month&amp;year=$prev_year' title='Previous Month'>&nbsp;<big>&laquo;&laquo;</big>&nbsp;Prev</a></td>\n";
echo "<td align='center'><a class='mcaldate2' href='#' title='Current Month'>&nbsp;".date("F Y",strtotime($cYear."-".$cMonth."-01"))."&nbsp;</a></td>\n";
echo "<td align='right'><a class='caldate3' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=$next_month&amp;year=$next_year' title='Next Month'>Next&nbsp;<big>&raquo;&raquo;</big>&nbsp;</a></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td colspan='3' height='5'></td>\n";
echo "</tr></table>\n";
echo "<table width='100%' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td class='norm'>\n";
echo "<table width='100%' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='1'><tr bgcolor='#000' height='20'>\n";
    foreach ($short_days as $key=>$val) {
echo "<td width='14%' align='center'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#ffff00;'><b>".$val."</b></span></td>\n"; 
        }
echo "</tr><tr>\n";
$s=date('w', mktime (0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear));
for ($ds=1; $ds<=$s; $ds++) {
echo "<td class='norm' height='20' align='center' valign='middle'></td>\n";
    }
for ($d=1; $d<=$endDate; $d++) {
if (date('w',mktime (0,0,0,$cMonth,$d,$cYear)) == 0) {
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
    }
$events = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE SUBSTR(date,7,4)='$cYear' AND month='$cMonth' AND day='$d'");
$rows  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($events);
        $post_id = $rows['id'];
        $post_title = $rows['title'];
        $evday = $rows['day'];
if ($evday) {
echo "<td height='20' class='event' align='center' valign='middle'>\n";
    } elseif ($d == $day && $cMonth == date('m')) {
echo "<td height='20' class='today' align='center' valign='middle'>\n";
    } else {
echo "<td height='20' class='norm' align='center' valign='middle'>\n";
}
if ($d == $day && $cMonth == date('m') && $d <> $evday) {
$d = str_pad($d,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "<span class='cal2'><a class='cal2' href='#' title='Today'>$d</a></span>\n";
    } elseif ($d == $day && $cMonth == date('m') && $d == $evday) {
$d = str_pad($d,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "<a class='cal2' href='post.php?id=$post_id' title='Today - $post_title'>$d</a>\n";
    } elseif ($evday) {
$d = str_pad($d,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "<a class='ecal' href='post.php?id=$post_id' title='$post_title'>$d</a>\n";
    } else {
$d = str_pad($d,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "<span class='noevt'>$d</span>\n";
    }
echo "</td>\n";
if (date('w',mktime (0,0,0,$cMonth,$d,$cYear)) == 6) {
echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table></td></tr><tr><td height='8'></td>\n";
echo "</tr></table>\n";
echo "</td></tr></table>\n";
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches _one_ row out of the result set. You are only _getting_ the first event out of multiple on the same day, because you are _fetching_ only the first one. You'll need a loop over _all_ the records the query returned in that place.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` only returns one row (as per the documentation). If you want more than one row, loop through it until it returns null (as per the examples in the documentation). https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php. Or consider using mysqli_fetch_all instead. Again...documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: @ ADyson After reading the manual about fetch_all I came up with this and need to know if it will work and how to display the result. `code`$rows  = mysqli_fetch_all($events, mysqli_assoc);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  ($post_id => $row['id'], $post_title => $row['title'], $evday => $row['day']);
}

Comment: If you want to know what it does, why not test it? But this code will loop over all the rows in the query results. Each time it loops it'll assign some values to variables, but then it will overwrite them the next time it runs. So if you want to do anything with the data, it would need to happen inside the loop, obviously. Or, outside the loop, you could find a specific row by one of its properties, and use it. Depends what the context is. Seems you're trying to populate a calendar, so perhaps first you need to work out which of the rows occur on which date?

Answer (score -1):

If the SQL query is correct and `$events` returns a valid result, use:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($events))
{
    # output events
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($row);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

As per [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` function fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an associative array. Each subsequent call to this function will return the next row within the result set (or null if there are no more rows), so we need to cycle through the result set by using a `while()` loop. (while there are results... do this).

To improve the code a bit more, you could first check if there are any results by using the `mysqli_num_rows` built-in function. If there aren't any events on a given calendar date, we don't need to loop through results, so we can skip that.

Your code could be something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM posts
        WHERE SUBSTR(date,7,4)='$cYear' AND month='$cMonth' AND day='$d'
        ";
$results = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($results)) // only if there are results
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
    {           
        $post_id = $row['id'];
        $post_title = $row['title'];
        // ...
        
        # output
        echo '<p>'.$post_title.'</p>';
    }
}
```

*Note* - I've changed your `$events` variable to `$results`, just for general best practice purposes and consistency, but technically that's not necessary.

*Also* - consider using the `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html)) in order to sort your events chronologically in the result set.
*Also* - consider using [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for your SQL queries, which are more secure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why don't you, instead of pointing out the code is vulnerable to SQL injection, just fix the problematic  code?

Comment: @DarkBee Hi, I'm giving an answer to his question, which is: how to show more than 1 event. By using a loop, you cycle through the results. The current code only fetches 1 event, which I'm explaining. Could you clarify what I should have said instead, please?

Comment: Use a prepared statement instead of just copying the vulnerable SQL?

Comment: @DarkBee It goes beyond the question. I could rewrite the whole calendar and bring up things like escaping and avoiding REQUEST vars, but it's not a security question, so I'm just giving it as a hint to stay on topic.

Comment: How is this beyond the question? If someone else just copy/paste this answer w/out reading through, then you provided them with an unsafe solution